In ptp4l source-code (version 3.1), clockadj.c file, clockadj_step() seems to be filling nanoseconds into tx.time.usec field
void clockadj_step(clockid_t clkid, int64_t step)
{
    struct timex tx;
    int64_t arg_step = step ;
    int sign = 1;
    if (step < 0) {
        sign = -1;
        step *= -1;
    }
    memset(&tx, 0, sizeof(tx));
    tx.modes = ADJ_SETOFFSET | ADJ_NANO;
    tx.time.tv_sec  = sign * (step / NS_PER_SEC);
    tx.time.tv_usec = sign * (step % NS_PER_SEC);
    /*
     * The value of a timeval is the sum of its fields, but the
     * field tv_usec must always be non-negative.
     */
    if (tx.time.tv_usec < 0) {
        tx.time.tv_sec  -= 1;
        tx.time.tv_usec += 1000000000;
    }
    if (clock_adjtime(clkid, &tx) < 0)
        pr_err("failed to step clock: %m");
}

https://github.com/richardcochran/linuxptp/blob/v3.1.x/clockadj.c
Question: Isnt tx.time.tv_usec supposed to be filled with microseconds?
For example, if value of input argument step=12345678, the clock should be corrected for 12345678 nanosecs = 12.345678 micoseconds
But above code seems to be filling the nanosecond value directly into tx.time.tv_usec. Whereas from struct timeval related man-pages, tv_usec has a value in the range 0 to 999,999.
